# Get the visible URL

Tags: php

I'm wondering how i can get URL (the visible one in the bar).
I have tried to google it, and lots of answers is to write this:

```
$url= "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

But it will get the path of the file you are in.
I would like to just get the visible url, like this:

```
www.something.com/index.php?page=teams
```

And then only get the url that you can see, and not the included url. When i do this, ill get something like:

```
 www.something.com/search.php
```

because im printing the URL inside the included file search.php.

I hope you understand my question, even though it's kinda bad written, i find it very hard to explain my problem.

Comment: Are you saying you want the URL minus the protocol? (`http://`)

Comment: No. I want the "visible" url. with question marks and stuff

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'visible' URL - In my case the entire URL is visible..

Comment: Okay. Im echoing the url inside search.php. That's i file i include in my script. Then if i uses the method shown before, it will display www.something.com/search.php. But that's not the url in the top. The URL In the top is www.something.com/index.php?page=teams and that's what i wan't to display

Comment: Ah OK, I understand a little better now. Is `search.php` `include`d into `index.php`?

Comment: Have you seen SteveBals' answer? That should work for you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for url :    `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

after ? in url :    `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't however not make it work.. It just doesnt display anything whenever im writting the query_string..

Comment: www.domain.com/?type=home

Comment: <?php
   echo $_GET['type'];  //output: home
?>

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
public function getUri()
{
    if (!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) or !isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) {
        return '';
    }
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($uri, $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) === 0) {
    $uri = substr($uri, strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
} elseif (strpos($uri, dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) === 0) {
    $uri = substr($uri, strlen(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])));
}
// This section ensures that even on servers that require the URI to be in the query string (Nginx) a correct
// URI is found, and also fixes the QUERY_STRING server var and $_GET array.
if (strncmp($uri, '?/', 2) === 0) {
    $uri = substr($uri, 2);
}
$uri = parse_url($uri, PHP_URL_PATH);
// Do some final cleaning of the URI and return it
    return str_replace(array('//', '../'), '/', trim($uri, '/'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

`$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`